# How would I set a data structure in redis as the value of another data structure

Tags: redis

I have a redis store that I'm setting up. I want the value for each insertion to be a sorted set. Within that sorted set, I want the values to be hashes. Would that be possible? Here is my data I want to place as a json representation:

```
{
    "siliconvalley": {
        "search-list": [
            {
                "id": "1234",
                "content-type": "VIDEO"
            },
            {
                "id": "456",
                "content-type": "SHOW"
            }

        ]
    }
}
```

To do a quick test in the redis cli, I attempted to do this:

//first creating a hashes key-value

```
HSET searchResult id "123"
```

//next creating my sorted set

```
ZADD siliconvalley 1 searchResult
```

however, that looks like it only stores a string in my set as "searchResult" and doesn't actually use the HSET I created

Comment: You can not make such manipulations in **Redis** but it will be better to use [ReJSON](https://redislabs.com/blog/redis-as-a-json-store/) if you want to make JSON related manipulations. By the use of ReJSON, you'll be able to create JSON objects in redis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis is a plain key-value store, it does't handle structured data. You can't store a hash inside a set. You need to use a document based database for this like mongo or couchdb.

What you can do in Redis is use a hash who's key is `siliconvalley:[searchIndexId]` and a sorted set `searchIndex` containing just ids as an index.

```
HSET searchResult:123 id "123"
HSET searchResult:123 content-type "VIDEO"
ZADD searchIndex 123

HSET searchResult:456 id "456"
HSET searchResult:456 content-type "SHOW"
ZADD searchIndex 456
```

Now you can fetch the id from `searchIndex` and use this id to fetch the value of the corresponding hash.